# Guest CentOS in virtualbox failed to load GNOME Power manager

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, virtualbox, gnome

I searched everywhere but not able to fix my problem. Can someone please help me?

Here are the details

1. I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as host OS.
2. I installed Oracle VirtualBox on it
3. Then I installed CentOS 6.6 as guest OS inside VirtualBox.

I was using it daily with no issues. Suddenly one day I saw a message that "Configuration defaults for gnome power manager has not been installed correctly", then I get login screen and after login nothing is displayed inside the VM window.

I used the gparted-live-0.22.0-2-i586.iso to go to its command prompt and there I used fdisk /dev/sda command to resize the partition.

Even after that I am not able to resolve the GNOME error and not able to login to centos inside virtualbox.

Can someone please help? Let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. At login prompt, press Ctrl-Alt-F2, this brings you to tty2, a text window. (You can try Ctrl-Alt-F1 to satisify your curiosity).
2. Login as root user.

   yum remove gnome-power-manager
   yum install gnome-power-manager
   reboot

I tried it on my system it works. One more thing, while installing gnome-power-manager if it shows some error regarding space issues just free some space for this installation